# A question about education system

Tags: soft-question

This question is because of an ongoing discussion which we have these days in Iran. The problem is about, so called, "Tizhooshan" (=very smart students)  schools in Iran. for these high schools, they hold an entrance exam (for students of  age 12) which its questions are completely based on their Math. and science lessons. Less than 10 percent of student which attend these exam can enter these "Tizhooshan" schools and difference between "Tizhooshan" schools and usual schools is than they have more time (1.5 and even 2 time) for Math. and science. Some people in Iran, including our minister of education, have argued that this separation of student has many bad consequences: It has bad psychological
effect on both students who fail this entrance exam and also on student which enter these schools (because of the label "very smart" which others  attach to them). Also (they argue) that this separation stops constructive relations between student which are strong in Math. and science with other students and prevents positive collaboration between them. Now it is my question:

QUESTION: is there high schools, similar to "Tizhooshan" schools in other countries?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Where i come from, "nail that stands out is hammered". Have you seen this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gifted_education and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gifted_and_talented_programmes?

Comment: @cgiovanardi  Thanks!  it seem very helpful.